# Block a specific page in Robots.txt

Tags: drupal-6, seo, robots.txt, google-search

According to this
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

`Disallow: /page1/`
all page1 URLs will be disallowed i.e page1/foo/bar will also get blocked.

`Disallow: /page1`

Only `page1` will be blocked and `page1/foo/bar will` be allowed.
But this is not happening , how can I block only `page1` and allow `page1/foo/bar` to be crawled

EDIT : 
Actual Issue is that same Page is crawled twice in different paths
as `/page` and `/page/`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a robots metatag?

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive"/>
```

Comment: Edited the question with actual issue, if I block the whole page then both results will be dropped. Now I am wondering if Canonical tag will be of help